# Push notification using GCM or services

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification

I am working on android application of geolocalisation, the idea is to get data from device installing in a car to the server, the data contain the speed of car, for exemple when the spped > 120 , we have to send notification to the application, so what is the bestway to do that: use GCM, timer or services..

any help please.

thank you.

Comment: Is the device installed in the car (which collects the data) the same device on which the application that would receive the notifications is installed, or are they separate devices?

Comment: @Eran separate devices

Comment: In that case how about bluetooth?

Answer (score 0):

GCM would probably be a good approach.

Even simpler (no need to write your own server) [parse.com](http://parse.com), they should also support GCM it seems but have only tried their own push implementation, and it works quite well.

Quick question: Why not let the device perform the notification by itself?